# SERVER_ERROR:[code] 1349195 [message]: The key hash does not match any stored key hashes Facebook Flutter

Tags: flutter, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-authentication

I'm working on Sign In with Facebook method, and it's working perfectly in the debug mode, but when I try to login in through the released APK from another account it shows the following error `SERVER_ERROR:[code] 1349195 [message]: The key hash does not match any stored key hashes`

I generated the hash key as provided in [Facebook's Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android)

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore" | "PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "PATH_TO_OPENSSL_LIBRARY\bin\openssl" base64
```

but it wasn't working.
I also tried this documentation ["Build and release an Android app"](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#reference-the-keystore-from-the-app) and many different solutions and nothing worked for my case

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you have to generate two key hashes, one for development, one for release.
to make your app work on other devices you must use the release key as mentioned in [Facebook's Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android).

Comment: yes, I added the upload-keystore.jks to my app Gradle by following  `Build and release an Android app` and added its hash to Facebook by using `keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

Comment: May be your release key hash is incorrect. If you have release SHA-1 then you can generate release Key hash using this tool http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php